# Cocoapods Mach-O Linker Errors after adding local dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I recently moved my data model objects to their own framework by adding clicking the + button on the project screen. I moved all the files and changed their target memberships to `AppCore` as opposed to `App`. The project is purely in Swift.

I updated my podfile to the below:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'App' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

    target 'AppCore' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

Whenever I try to build I get 4 errors:

`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDataSnapshot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SSWorkout.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SSReference.o
      objc-class-ref in SSReferrable.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SSUser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabaseReference", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SSOperation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have deintegrated and reinstalled pods, cleaned the project, cleaned build folder, deleted derived data etc, I can't get it to compile.

You can reproduce this in the demo project, run `pod install` and try to build.

https://github.com/Raesu/Demo-Proj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries in Firebase's pod are currently built as static libraries. It is not possible to link static libraries into a dynamic library framework -
 DemoCore in your example.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, I can't use my own framework like in the demo until firebase is built as a dynamic library?

Comment: Not without a lot of contortions. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/build.swift for an example of what it would take.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling bitcode in Xcode build settings and do a clean build, this helps me to resolve the issue

```
Xcode > Build settings> Enable bitcode
```